# C# - How to convert an Image into an 8-bit color Image?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, color-depth

I need to convert a PNG Image loaded from a file into an 8 bit-per-pixel byte array used by another device (embedded programming).

I'm copying over pixel by pixel into a new Image created with a 16-bit color - `Format16bppRgb565`, but I need `Format8bpp`, which is not present in the .NET Framework. (I cannot use `Format8bppIndexed` since the other device cannot handle indexed bitmaps)

```
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imgPath);
 Bitmap img8 = new Bitmap(imgW, imgH, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);
 for (int I = 0; I <= img.Width - 1; I++) {
     for (int J = 0; J <= img.Height - 1; J++) {
         img8.SetPixel(I, J, img.GetPixel(I, J));
     }
 }
```

So how can I convert an Image into an 8-bit per pixel byte array?

- Can I use the 8-bit indexed format and extract the bytes? - `Format8bppIndexed`
- Can I calculate the pixel colors by reducing the 32-bit color R,G,B values to 8-bit?
- Is there a C# library that does this already?
- "The easiest way is to create a new 8 bit bitmap, and draw your 24 bit image onto it." - how?

Comment: You say your device cannot do indexed. So how does it use 8 bits per pixel? Is it greyscale?

Comment: Or does it have 2 bits for red, 3 bits for green, and 3 bits for blue, or something like that?

Comment: Hardest part from what I can see would be generating the actual palette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure how to do it with plain vanilla C# you can use the [FreeImage Project](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) libraries to convert images formats:

> FreeImage is an Open Source library
>   project for developers who would like
>   to support popular graphics image
>   formats like PNG, BMP, JPEG, TIFF and
>   others as needed by today's multimedia
>   applications. FreeImage is easy to
>   use, fast, multithreading safe,
>   compatible with all 32-bit versions of
>   Windows, and cross-platform (works
>   both with Linux and Mac OS X).

It's written in C++ but has good .NET wrappers you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I already did it in one Pattern Recognition project. Searching some image processing and pattern recognition books you can find these solutions.

**a)**  If you want to convert to greyscale you can find in general two solutions.

*#1* Averaging  RGB channels. - You can take 8-bit values for avery single channel and calculate  pixel = ( R+G+B )/3

*#2* Take only the Green component.  It is best viewed.

**b)** If you want to convert to 8bit color representation you need to use a Color table.
    You can see a solution here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Image_Bitdepth_Conversion.aspx